# DC Flickering, wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxruby

I am using the class below for adding rubberbands. However, everytime that I create the rubberband(left click), there is a flicker/flash. I do not know why this is happening. Also, I am putting the rubberband in a ScrolledWindow.

```
import wx
class wxPyRubberBander:
    """ A class to manage mouse events/ rubberbanding of a wx.Python
        canvas object """

    def __init__(self, canvas):

        # canvas object
        self._canvas = canvas
        # mouse selection start point
        self.m_stpoint=wx.Point(0,0)
        # mouse selection end point
        self.m_endpoint=wx.Point(0,0)
        # mouse selection cache point
        self.m_savepoint=wx.Point(0,0)

        # flags for left click/ selection
        self._leftclicked=False
        self._selected=False

        # Register event handlers for mouse
        self.RegisterEventHandlers()

    def RegisterEventHandlers(self):
        """ Register event handlers for this object """

        wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN(self._canvas, self.OnMouseEvent)
        wx.EVT_LEFT_UP(self._canvas, self.OnMouseEvent)
        wx.EVT_MOTION(self._canvas, self.OnMouseEvent)


    def OnMouseEvent(self, event):
        """ This function manages mouse events """


        if event:

            # set mouse cursor
            # get device context of canvas
            dc= wx.ClientDC(self._canvas)
            # Set logical function to XOR for rubberbanding
            dc.SetLogicalFunction(wx.XOR)

            # Set dc brush and pen
            # Here I set brush and pen to white and grey respectively
            # You can set it to your own choices

            # The brush setting is not really needed since we
            # dont do any filling of the dc. It is set just for 
            # the sake of completion.

            wbrush = wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255,255,255), wx.TRANSPARENT)
            wpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(200, 200, 200), 1, wx.SOLID)
            dc.SetBrush(wbrush)
            dc.SetPen(wpen)


        if event.LeftDown():

           # Left mouse button down, change cursor to
           # something else to denote event capture
           self.m_stpoint = event.GetPosition()

           # invalidate current canvas
           self._canvas.Refresh()
           # cache current position
           self.m_savepoint = self.m_stpoint
           self._selected = False
           self._leftclicked = True

        elif event.Dragging():   

            # User is dragging the mouse, check if
            # left button is down

            if self._leftclicked:

                # reset dc bounding box
                dc.ResetBoundingBox()
                dc.BeginDrawing()
                w = (self.m_savepoint.x - self.m_stpoint.x)
                h = (self.m_savepoint.y - self.m_stpoint.y)

                # To erase previous rectangle
                dc.DrawRectangle(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w, h)

                # Draw new rectangle
                self.m_endpoint =  event.GetPosition()

                w = (self.m_endpoint.x - self.m_stpoint.x)
                h = (self.m_endpoint.y - self.m_stpoint.y)

                # Set clipping region to rectangle corners
                dc.SetClippingRegion(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w,h)
                dc.DrawRectangle(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w, h) 
                dc.EndDrawing()

                self.m_savepoint = self.m_endpoint # cache current endpoint

        elif event.LeftUp():

            # User released left button, change cursor back   
            self._selected = True  #selection is done
            self._leftclicked = False # end of clicking  


    def GetCurrentSelection(self):
        """ Return the current selected rectangle """

        # if there is no selection, selection defaults to
        # current viewport

        left = wx.Point(0,0)
        right = wx.Point(0,0)

        # user dragged mouse to right
        if self.m_endpoint.y > self.m_stpoint.y:
            right = self.m_endpoint
            left = self.m_stpoint
        # user dragged mouse to left
        elif self.m_endpoint.y < self.m_stpoint.y:
            right = self.m_stpoint
            left = self.m_endpoint

        return (left.x, left.y, right.x, right.y)


    def ClearCurrentSelection(self):
        """ Clear the current selected rectangle """

        box = self.GetCurrentSelection()

        dc=wx.ClientDC(self._canvas)

        w = box[2] - box[0]
        h = box[3] - box[1]
        dc.SetClippingRegion(box[0], box[1], w, h)
        dc.SetLogicalFunction(wx.XOR)

        # The brush is not really needed since we
        # dont do any filling of the dc. It is set for 
        # sake of completion.

        wbrush = wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255,255,255), wx.TRANSPARENT)
        wpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(200, 200, 200), 1, wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetBrush(wbrush)
        dc.SetPen(wpen)
        dc.DrawRectangle(box[0], box[1], w,h)
        self._selected = False 

        # reset selection to canvas size
        self.ResetSelection()    

    def ResetSelection(self):
        """ Resets the mouse selection to entire canvas """

        self.m_stpoint = wx.Point(0,0)
        sz=self._canvas.GetSize()
        w,h=sz.GetWidth(), sz.GetHeight()
        self.m_endpoint = wx.Point(w,h)
```

Comment: try looking into doublebuffering

Comment: Yes I tried, but I am running into problems using DB, Can you provide an example on how I could fix this? It only flickers when it gets created.

Comment: probably easier (and might work) to just freeze it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe freezing it would work

```
 def OnMouseEvent(self, event):
    """ This function manages mouse events """
    if not self._canvas.IsFrozen(): #prevent multiple freezes
        self._canvas.Freeze() #freeze it from updates
    if event:

        # set mouse cursor
        # get device context of canvas
        dc= wx.ClientDC(self._canvas)
        # Set logical function to XOR for rubberbanding
        dc.SetLogicalFunction(wx.XOR)

        # Set dc brush and pen
        # Here I set brush and pen to white and grey respectively
        # You can set it to your own choices

        # The brush setting is not really needed since we
        # dont do any filling of the dc. It is set just for 
        # the sake of completion.

        wbrush = wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255,255,255), wx.TRANSPARENT)
        wpen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour(200, 200, 200), 1, wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetBrush(wbrush)
        dc.SetPen(wpen)


    if event.LeftDown():

       # Left mouse button down, change cursor to
       # something else to denote event capture
       self.m_stpoint = event.GetPosition()

       # invalidate current canvas
       self._canvas.Refresh()
       # cache current position
       self.m_savepoint = self.m_stpoint
       self._selected = False
       self._leftclicked = True

    elif event.Dragging():   

        # User is dragging the mouse, check if
        # left button is down

        if self._leftclicked:

            # reset dc bounding box
            dc.ResetBoundingBox()
            dc.BeginDrawing()
            w = (self.m_savepoint.x - self.m_stpoint.x)
            h = (self.m_savepoint.y - self.m_stpoint.y)

            # To erase previous rectangle
            dc.DrawRectangle(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w, h)

            # Draw new rectangle
            self.m_endpoint =  event.GetPosition()

            w = (self.m_endpoint.x - self.m_stpoint.x)
            h = (self.m_endpoint.y - self.m_stpoint.y)

            # Set clipping region to rectangle corners
            dc.SetClippingRegion(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w,h)
            dc.DrawRectangle(self.m_stpoint.x, self.m_stpoint.y, w, h) 
            dc.EndDrawing()

            self.m_savepoint = self.m_endpoint # cache current endpoint

    elif event.LeftUp():

        # User released left button, change cursor back   
        self._selected = True  #selection is done
        self._leftclicked = False # end of clicking  
    if self._canvas.IsFrozen(): #prevent multiple thaws
        self._canvas.Thaw() #thaw it so it updates
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now its even worse, It flickers everytime I move the mouse (wx.EVT_MOTION)

Comment: I dunno I just tested your code and I get flicker the whole time I am dragging... but not on click...

Comment: Ok nvm, I just found a great example, http://www.ida.liu.se/~ETE257/timetable/LectureWxPython.html, Works like a charm!, Double Buffering was the solution. Now there, is no flickering at all, even if I refresh!!